# How can I send a Privatemsg using Rules and have the name of the site as the sender?

Tags: 7, rules, privatemsg

I am using the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and I am trying to set up an automatically generated welcome message to new members registering on the site. This message will go into the new member's inbox.

I do not see a token that would allow the site's name to be the sender. All I see is the token for the logged in user. As expected, this doesn't trigger the message.

I have toyed with the [account] token. So when John creates an account, the message comes from John himself. This would be acceptable but it isn't consistent: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I know some tokens exist that are not always displayed. Does anyone have the name of the mysterious token? Or the magic to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an account for sending the messages and in rules, use direct input and enter its user id. That way, you could also see replies to welcome message.

Comment: This approach only works if the account is an administrator and creates a new account for a user (token is "logged-in-user".) But with a newcomer creating his own account, no message is sent. There isn't the possibility of assigning a certain user or the site as the sender.

Comment: Did you click "Switch to Direct Input Mode" in the rules action for "Send message" and enter the uid of the sender?

Comment: @NiallMurphy : even though it was not part of the question, you could take this a step further, using [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) and its integration with the Privatemsg module ... to produce such "shiny" iOS style of (red) msg notification ...

Comment: Good idea! I've never seen that module before..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the site name token: [site:name]

Full list of tokens: https://www.drupal.org/node/390482

Comment: Unfortunately, this token is not accepted by privatemsg.